# Nullpointer exception in android API level 21

Tags: android

In my application I am using following code:

```
 final String cachePath = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
            !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() ? getExternalCacheDir(context).getPath()
            : context.getCacheDir().getPath();
```

Above code run fine on android version pre lolipop, But on API level 21 I am getting dollowing error as:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getPath()' on a null object reference
```

Any suggestion will  be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the code you posted, did you right this yourself?:

```
final String cachePath = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
            !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() ? getExternalCacheDir(context).getPath()
            : context.getCacheDir().getPath();
```

You got the most common error in Android, a `NullPointerException`:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getPath()' on a null object reference
```

You are calling `getPath()` twice without checking for `null`.

Try this:

```
String cachePath; // you still need a default value if not mounted

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) || !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
    if (getExternalCacheDir(context) != null) {
        cachePath = getExternalCacheDir(context).getPath(); // most likely your null value
    }
} else {
    if (context.getCacheDir() != null) {
        cachePath = context.getCacheDir().getPath();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this same problem and found I was getting a lot of null pointer exceptions reported, it actually comes from the developer documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

In which case is it failing?  The docs say it's possible for getExternalCacheDir to return null.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29