# Android getExternalCacheDir() exact location

Tags: android

I am using below method to save one image file in the cache of my app.

```
   File path=getActivity().getExternalCacheDir();
```

In my log i am getting that my image is saved in my internal storage of my phone
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/me.XXX.xxx/cacheimagefile100.png` and i can access that image file for sharing to other apps using intents. But some of the users using my app getting error in this line of code like

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.app.Activity.getExternalCacheDir()' on a null object
```

I dont know why it is getting. Even my app is a using internal storage (OS VERSION Android 7) not the external SD Card storage cache.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason behind that?
What is the good fix for this? 
I used getCacheDir() method. But when i am sharing the file through intent(Basically it is image) the image is empty and null. Tell me a fix for this.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29286111/1649353

Comment: getActivity() returned null. So you have `null.getExternalCacheDir();`

Comment: I am using fragment. So for context i am using getActivity() method @greenapps

Comment: Yes i understand. But `getActivity()==null`. Now what are you going to do? The least you can do is checking for null before use.